# NLB - Stop IIS Site 1 - Will it now alway go to IIS Site 2?

Tags: windows, iis, nlb

With Windows Network Load Balancer (nlb) if I turn OFF a single IIS Site on Box 1

Will traffic be automatically redirected to the same corresponding site on Box 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

NLB works at layer 3, not at layer 7. As long as the NLB heartbeats are exchanged between Box 1 and Box 2 then NLB will continue to send traffic to Box 2. You may be interested in the following:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-(arr)/achieving-high-availability-and-scalability-arr-and-nlb